# Do I need to add any setup if I want to run a cloned flutter project from github?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

My friends and I are working on a flutter side project that uses firebase. He already wrote some code and I am just trying to run on ios development since I am the only mac user of the team. After opening the project, I am getting some errors in both xcode and vscode. Do I need to add any extra setup in order to run the project on ios? Thank you in advance! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgvFs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s5C9.png)

Comment: I think you have not done registration for projectfor IOS on firebase. If not then setup your ios project to firebase also. That will solve issue. other than this only think you need to check is packages. you need to run pub get in pubspec.yaml

Comment: are you talking about the info.plist file?

Comment: No. Registration on firebase itself. You go to firebase and link your project with the firebase.